# Why do member types need to be forward declared while member functions needn't?

Tags: c++, class, types, standards, member-functions

```
struct A
{
    void f1()
    {
        f2(); // ok, though f2() is not declared before
    }

    void f2()
    {}

    void f3(X*) // error: unknown type name 'X'
    {}

    struct X
    {};
};

int main()
{
    A a;
}
```

**Why do member types need to be forward declared while member functions needn't?**

Comment: You can think of it as if the function bodies actually occur after the class definition, e.g. this code is almost identical to `struct A { void f1(); void f2(); .... };` followed by `inline void A::f1() { f2(); }`

Comment: A point about jumping to conclusions: did you try something like `void f1() { X obj; f2(); }`? You identified "type vs. function" when the differentiator is something else. (Jumping to conclusions is not all bad, but it's wise to know when you are doing it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to do with the [*complete-class context*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class#mem-6).  When you are in the body of a member function, the class is considered complete and can use anything defined in the class, no matter where in the class it is declared.

The function parameters are not part of that context so they must be types that are known about at the point you try to use them.